# Зачем нужны произвольные теги

Tags: html, yandex-maps-api

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста, на некоторых сайтах встречаю произвольные теги. Например тег ymaps(яндекс карт) [ссылка](https://hh.ru/search/vacancy?items_on_page=100&only_with_salary=true&area=1&enable_snippets=true&label=with_address&clusters=true&search_field=name&text=&salary=&isMap=true&bottom_left_lat=55.6849210531&bottom_left_lng=37.0858680221&top_right_lat=55.8724156052&top_right_lng=37.429190776). В этом примере сама карта это обновляемый canvas. завернут в тег ymaps.(тег появляется в конечном дереве DOM после отработки JS-скриптов я так понимаю) В чем приемущества произвольных тегов? Они ведут себя как обычный блочный элемент(скажем div)?

Comment: Возможно [этот пост](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395072/generating-selecting-non-standard-html-tags-with-jquery-a-good-idea) вам поможет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это `xml` теги и ведут они себя так как нужно разработчикам

```
.ymaps-2-1-48-map {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    display: block; ...
```

У яндекса полно таких тегов noindex тот же, правда это уже `html` тег

Comment: любые xml теги корректно обрабатываются в html документе? (с DOCTYPE html).

Comment: c js вместе, то по карте видно, что отлично обрабатываются )